# Не работает поиск по БД код, который работает в контроллере

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть контроллер, в который я инжектирую переменную

```
@Autowired
ClientRepo clientRepo;
```

Сам интерфейс ClientRepo выглядит так

```
public interface ClientRepo extends JpaRepository<Client, Integer> {
Client findByWhatsapp (String string);}
```

Сам контроллер

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
    @PostMapping
    public String addIncomingRequest(@RequestBody IncRequestClientTypeIncRequestDTO incRequestDTO) { 
System.out.println(clientRepo.findByWhatsapp(whatsapp));}
```

работает корректно

Создал класс, чтобы не захламлять контроллер

```
public class IncomingRequestSer {
    private static ClientRepo clientRepo;
    public static void addIncomingRequest(IncRequestClientTypeIncRequestDTO incRequestDTO){
Client client1 = clientRepo.findByWhatsapp(whatsapp)}
```

Выдаёт ошибку, хотя если вывести отдельно просто номер whatsapp

```
System.out.println(whatsapp);
```

То номер whatsapp выводится корректно

Он только не ищет по БД - ошибка - мол ничего не найдено - null

Comment: Где находится конфигурация, а каких файлах?

Comment: Стандартно, в application properties/ Вы эот имели в виду?

Comment: Не совсем, мне просто нужно знать откуда загружать файлы конфигурации.